# Calculate unique dates from multiple columns

Tags: excel, countif, date-range

I have three ranges of dates in Columns B7:B38, F7:F38 and K7:K38. Some dates are duplicates and some dates are unique. Some columns contains few values, and some columns are full. Which formula I can use to calculate unique dates value?
I find formula that work fine for one range, but can't figure out how to compare multiple ranges

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B7:B38;B7:B38))
```

If I use COUNTIFS for multiple ranges

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS(B7:B38;B7:B38;F7:F38;F7:F38;K7:K38;K7:K38))
```

it calculate only one longest range of values.

Any advices? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hello Igor Oleksandrov,

I could not manage to do it in one formula but I think I have a solution for you: List the contents of your ranges with two passes of the `small` function. The Duplicates can be removed with some comparing in the middle.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

In the first version of my answer I put the ranges in a name. That might be handy and nice, but luckily the `small` function can handle multiple ranges when in `()`.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Wolfgang Jacques. I got my desire result in a shorter way. I placed all dates to one column on Sheet2!A1:A96 and with previous formula calculated sum of unique values.